# Como adicionar uma descrição na coluna?

Tags: sql-server, migrations

Estou usando Firts Migration para atualizar no Banco de Dados MS SQL SERVER.

Na classe `ApplicationDBContext`, tem um método `OnModelCreating` onde você pode renomear tabela, alterar tipo de dados, definir suas chaves, etc...

Nesse método `OnModelCreating`, eu consigo colocar a descrição da coluna ?

Segue exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Confere aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080601/how-to-add-description-to-columns-in-entity-framework-4-3-code-first-using-migra

Answer (score 0):

Oi, Matheus. Tudo bem?

Não tenho experiência com o First Migration, mas talvez eu possa abrir o leque de possibilidades.

No SQL Server esse tipo de informação é armazenada em uma tabela Extended Properties.

Da mesma forma que você gerou os scripts das tabelas e dos seus respectivos dados a serem migrados, entendo que, basta migrar os dados dessa tabela de propriedade extendida pelo script do First Migration.

Segue abaixo alguns procedimentos que podem te ajudar, ou pelo menos te dar um norte.

```
USE AdventureWorks;  

CREATE TABLE dbo.T1 (id int , name char (20));  


--Adiciona a propriedade extendida 
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty   
     @name = N'Caption'  
    ,@value = N'Employee ID'  
    ,@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = dbo  
    ,@level1type = N'Table',  @level1name = T1  
    ,@level2type = N'Column', @level2name = id;  


--Atualiza a propriedade extendida 
EXEC sp_updateextendedproperty   
     @name = N'Caption'  
    ,@value = 'Employee ID must be unique.'  
    ,@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = dbo  
    ,@level1type = N'Table',  @level1name = T1  
    ,@level2type = N'Column', @level2name = id;  


--Consulta propriedades extendidas 
SELECT  major_id, minor_id, t.name AS [Table Name], c.name AS [Column Name],  
        ep.name AS [Extended Property name], ep.value AS [Extended Property value]
FROM sys.extended_properties AS ep
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON ep.major_id = t.object_id 
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON ep.major_id = c.object_id AND ep.minor_id = c.column_id
WHERE class = 1
and t.name = 'T1'
```

Espero que isso te ajude. Se precisar de juda pode me contatar, ficarei feliz em ajudar.

Abs.,
Welricsson Carmo